# Is it possible to reset the equation number arbitrarily, in-document?

Tags: equations, counters

I do my homework with LaTeX and it is often just a few pages, so I don't have different sections or anything like that. I would just like to be able to reset the equation counter after each exercise that I do.

Is it possible for me to type in a command, such as `\reset` whenever I want in the document, and have the equation counter reset to 1?

Comment: You can also have the equation counter reset every time you increnent another counter, like the exercise number.  Something like `\@addtoreset{equaton}`{exercise}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure!

Your `\reset` would be equivalent to `\setcounter{equation}{0}`. Perhaps you want to add

```
\newcommand{\eqnumreset}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
```

somewhere in your preamble. This would allow you to use `\eqnumreset` before any equation you want to have starting from (1) again.

Note that this might be problematic if you are using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), together with `\label`s and `\ref`s to the equations. A work-around is possible though.

Comment: Thanks!              ..........